# Can't execute an app on my device xCode - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm creating an iOS app and I'm about to test it on a real device.
The problem is that when I compile and run an app on the iOS simulator it works fine. When I try to test it on my iPhone X (256GB, iOS 11.4) the app crashes. The error says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver ([controller name]) has no segue with identifier 'nonLogged''

I'm pretty sure that the name in the storyboard is correct.
I've also commented that part of code as shown down below but it gives me the error either.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("prima di fare la presunta segue")
    /*if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nonLogged", sender: nil)
    }*/
}
```

Comment: it is working in simulator ?

Comment: yeah, as i said it work in simulator